# Are software-specific command tags... appropriate?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just reviewed a question with a [vrt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vrt) tag, and not knowing what it referred to I noticed the Wiki hadn't been filled out. So I went to create that one and also noticed a [gdalbuildvrt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gdalbuildvrt) tag that wasn't filled out either. I debated on whether to raise the issue as a synonym candidate, but decided one is a tool and one is a format.

However I got to thinking about how many times I see questions asked about a particular ArcGIS tool (say, Viewshed or Service Area Analysis/Layer) and I can't ever recall seeing a tag for them when I go to look. Which makes sense - do you really want the potential for every command (as opposed to extension or maybe even plugin) of every software to have its own tag? And so often what they *do* (interpolate, viewshed) is more important than the specific software's tool name. So I thought maybe [gdalbuildvrt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gdalbuildvrt) should just be deleted as a tag. Most of the questions had [vrt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vrt) anyway.

At the same time I noticed what seemed like inconsistent formatting with that command tag, so I did a search on all "gdal" tags. Sure enough, there are several command specific tags, and there's a pretty good mix of "gdal-command" and "gdalcommand". I gather from some other Meta questions that creating the hyphen versions (which are easier to read) and then making synoyms out of the current ones is the way to go. I don't know if you can *edit* an existing tag, but I wouldn't have the rep anyway unless it's a mod only thing. And as so often happens, I can see an error in the tag but don't have a sufficient score enough to be able to suggest synonyms.

**So, to summarize:**

- Should software-specific *command* tags be used/allowed/etc.?
- Can somebody clean up the gdal tags to a consistent formatting?
  (Thank you.)

Answer (score 2):

I think new tags, as long as they conform to the [GIS Stack Exchange tag naming conventions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), are fine to coin as long as they are expected to be used a few hundred times in the next few years.  The exact number of times is left deliberately inexact because it is a "rule of thumb" only.

In general, I think command/tool/dialog/window specific tags are likely to be too fine-grained but some like [field-calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-calculator), [union](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/union), [dissolve](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dissolve), etc, probably attract the volume of questions to warrant them.  These may not be software-specific but are the first examples that come to mind.

I think [gdalbuildvrt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gdalbuildvrt) should probably be a synonym of [gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gdal), but [vrt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vrt) seems to be getting used more of late so I would lean toward leaving that.

Comment: Ah, but those aren't software specific - they either describe generic tools found in multiple softwares under the same name, or general GIS/spatial concepts (ok, so the dissolve tag needs a little work there).

Comment: @ChrisW True - but they are so well known that I think they help illustrate that it is the space between too coarse and too fine based on likely use that helps position a tag in the useful band.

Comment: So there should be trim, clip, intersect, join, output tags from this logic? Where does in between stop?

Comment: Clip & join I think yes; intersect debatable; trim no - no science is being claimed

Comment: A good example of an appropriate command tag is [tag:ogr2ogr]; it's very versatile and popular.

Comment: @martinf I agree, with 184 questions, it is well and truly justified.  Conversely, I just noticed [tag:ogr2gui] with just one tagged question, and only mentioned in 5 questions in 4 years (http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=ogr2gui) so I just untagged that one which should mean the tag disappears within 24 hours.

Comment: @martinf I should *really* learn gdal, but... My first thought was "hey, isn't that a standalone module or tool?" My next thought after looking was "shouldn't that be gdal-ogr2ogr?" Then I looked at the gdal ref page and how the 'included utilities' variable had no space, underscore, and dash in their names (which I didn't know when earlier examining the "gdal" tags. And now I wonder what can of worms I have opened here, and if gdal needs a question like PolyGeo's [on ArcGIS](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/using-tags-on-arcgis-questions).